# Merge [oneplus-two] and [oneplus-2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup

I recently came across [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/142813/95577), and saw the question was tagged with both [oneplus-two](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneplus-two) and [oneplus-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneplus-2).

Shouldn't they be merged into one tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree. As the 1+1 uses [oneplus-one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneplus-one), I'd say [oneplus-two](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneplus-two) should be the one to stay. There's no [oneplus-1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneplus-1) synonym, so I guess we don't want [oneplus-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneplus-2) stay as such?

Comment: Synonyms don't hurt anything as long as they're unambiguous, so I went ahead and merged with the synonym.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewRead – I've set `status-completed` for this one then :)